# do not extend React.Component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

the es6 syntax for creating React component is `export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component`.However it still work when `export default class ExampleComponent` without `extends React.Component` on condition that `import React from 'react'`; why this happen

Comment: The former has access to lifecycle methods (e.g. `componentDidMount`), while the latter does not; it is a static component.

Comment: @lux The latter do has access to `render `    check this https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example

Comment: And only `render()`, per the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components --> `"These components behave just like a React class with only a render method defined"`

Comment: One last thing, a recommended read for this exact situation: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.p48c3db01 And written by the fellow who penned the repo you referenced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between plain es6 class and extend React.Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666921/what-are-the-differences-between-plain-es6-class-and-extend-react-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to be in this situation and miss what's happening, but the difference is really huge: without extending React.Component, you're just creating a JS class. Furthermore:

- because it satisfies the requirements of a React Class (which you can create with either `React.createClass()` or as an ES6 class), it'll still "work",
- **but** you won't get lifeCyle methods or access to state (someone correct me if I'm wrong about this, pretty certain you wouldn't with just a class bc there's no backing instance attached).
- these "simpler" components are generally faster for React to deal with and require less "machinery", since they're just a (hopefully) pure function that renders something.
- so, they key difference here is that with just a class that has a render method you're not "requiring" as much. this should be enough *most* of the time; you shouldn't need access to `state` for everything

Hope that helps!

Comment: React documentation on this topic: 
 https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.  I agree with @markthethomas.  From the docs:  "...components defined as classes have some additional features. Local state is exactly that: a feature available only to classes."  The docs don't state this explicitly for lifecycle hooks, but the same is clearly true for those.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a "pure" [JavaScript class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), but once it is not extending a `React.Component` you will be unable to access specific React behavior. Check [how extends work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends).

Comment: check this https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example ,a lot of React component do not extend React.Component but still works fine

Comment: I believe this is because of this deprecated library: https://github.com/gaearon/react-pure-render